# Maven Tomcat Deploy Fails with Non-Blank Password

Tags: tomcat7, maven-3

I'm able to ***successfully*** deploy my war to tomcat via the maven tomcat plugin when the password is ***blank***:

settings.xml

```
<server>
  <id>local_tomcat</id>
  <username>admin</username>
  <password></password>
</server>
```

tomcat-users.xml

```
<role rolename="manager-gui" />
<role rolename="manager-script" />
<user username="admin" password="" roles="tomcat,admin,manager-gui,manager-script" />
```

However, if I only change the password to be non-blank (e.g. foobar) and restart tomcat then I can't deploy anymore:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project myapp: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8080/manager/html/deploy?path=%2Fmyapp&war= -> [Help 1]
```

Any idea what might cause that?

**EDIT:**

My pom.xml has:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
     <server>local_tomcat</server>
     <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [docs](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html) you shouldn't define the server tag in the configuration block of the plugin in case of an empty password.

Furthermore i would suggest to use the [tomcat-maven-plugin of Apache](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/)

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked with tomcat 7 and the tomcat-maven-plugin from Apache, when using the text manager endpoint (`http://localhost:8080/manager/text`) and a user that has only the manager-script role assigned (and not manager-gui). See also http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/